# When clicking on route button bootstrap and js files are not load Angular 13

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4

I am new in angular and converting html template to angular for learning, but i am facing a problem when i goto the signup page from home's routerlink, the bootstrap and js files not loaded and when i do the page refresh in signup button then bootstrap and js files are loaded.

**Route button:**
**Header.component.html**

`<li><a href="lead.index" routerLink="signup" routerLinkActive="active">Sign up <span class="ti-user"></span></a></li>`

**app-routing.module.ts:**

```
`const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: '', component:HomeComponent},
  {path:'signup',component:SignupComponent}

];`
```

**app.component.html**

```
`<app-header *ngIf="showHead"></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

`<app-footer *ngIf="showHead"></app-footer>`
```

Note: If I use  component in app.component.html and then i click to route button in navbar then all the bootstrap and js files load, but this is not my requirement, because when i did this then signup page show me in Index page also.

```
`<app-header *ngIf="showHead"></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

`<app-signup></app-signup>
<app-footer *ngIf="showHead"></app-footer>`
```

[Through router link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrfx6.png)

[On Page Refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9g8N.png)

Code link:
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1DRmKnnEpE-lEX6iw3lLUXmh6ofVpFONQ

Comment: `{path: '', component:HomeComponent}` your this line should be very first in routes array file. then after so just re-arrange this.

Comment: @GRD I have try this but still not working. Scripts are loaded if refresh the page. but if I come through routerlink the scripts are not loaded and java scripts/bootstrap don't work.

Comment: try ading `/`  to the routerlink and remove the "lead.index": `<a routerLink="/signup" routerLinkActive="active">..`. In Angular you has an unique index.html. the router is who mannage to show one or another component based in your path

Comment: @Eliseo I followed the instructions but still the case is same :(

Comment: @Khurram is there any way so that i can see your code ?

Comment: @GRD Please find the code in mentioned link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DRmKnnEpE-lEX6iw3lLUXmh6ofVpFONQ?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

i downloaded the file and it works perfectly on reloads and navigating with routerlink.
maybe its because of your browser cache. refresh that and try again.

Comment: No, It is not working. And it is not about routerlink, It is about when clicking on routerlink the js and css files are not loading. just go to singup page from routing and observe even floating label not working.

Comment: I add the screenshots in question please see them.